# Prove that exists $x\in[0,2]$ such that $f(x)=\frac{1}{x}$.

Tags: calculus, continuity

Let $f$ be a continuous function in the interval $[0,2]$ such that $f(2)=3$. Prove that exists $x\in[0,2]$ such that $f(x)=1/x$.

So I've tried defining a new function $g$ such that $g(x)=f(x)-1/x$ although it didn't lead me anywhere, I tried getting to a situation where I can use the IVT although it seems my attempts haven't gotten me anywhere.

I haven't used any math formatting in my post because I'm not too familiar with the formatting syntax, due to my studies not being in English.

Hopefully if a mod sees my post, they will be able to update my post according to the right formats.

Thanks in advance for any advice!

Comment: Notice $g(2)=2.5$ and $\lim_{x\to 0^+} g(x)=-\infty$ (prove this!), and so there is some $t\in (0, 2)$ where $g(t)<0$, by definition. Can you continue from here?

Comment: Step 1: Prove that there exists $a \in (0, 2)$ such that $f(a) < 1/x$. This should be pretty straightforward if you use the fact that $f$ is continuous at $0$. Step 2: consider the function $g(x) = f(x) - 1/x$, note that $g(3) > 0$ while $g(a) < 0$, and apply the intermediate value theorem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try $g(x) = x f(x)$ and the IVT

Comment: This is clever.